# How would you update a post in Flask SQL alchemy

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

**views.py file**

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request, session,escape, abort ,g
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required, LoginManager
from app import app, db
from .models import User, Post

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

login_manager.login_view = 'login'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title="home")



@app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('register.html')
    user = User(request.form['username'] , request.form['password'] )
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('User successfully registered')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html')

    username = session['username'] = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    registered_user = User.query.filter_by(username=username,password=password).first()
    if registered_user is None:
        flash('Username or Password is invalid' , 'error')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    login_user(registered_user)
    flash('Logged in successfully')
    return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('index'))

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index')) 



@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user

@app.route('/posts')
def posts():

        return render_template("posts.html", posts=Post.query.all())



@app.route('/posts/create_post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_post():
    if request.method == 'GET':
         return render_template('create_post.html')
    else:
        title = request.form['title']
        body = request.form['body']
        post = Post(title=title, body=body)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('posts'))




@app.route('/posts/<int:id>')
@login_required
def show(id):
    return render_template("post.html", post=Post.query.get(id), pid=id )


@app.route('/posts/delete/<int:id>')
@login_required
def delete(id):
    post = Post.query.get(id)
    if post is None:
        flash('Post not found.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    db.session.delete(post)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Your post has been deleted.')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/posts/edit/<int:id>',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit(id):

    post = Post.query.get(id)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("edit.html", post=Post.query.get(id), pid=id )

    title = request.form['title']
    body = request.form['body']

    edit = Post(title=title, body=body)

    db.session.add(edit)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Your post has been deleted.')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))



@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

**edit.html file**

```
<h1>Edit</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('posts/edit', id=id) }}">
    <label>Title</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="title"></br>
    <label>Body</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="body"></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

Pretty much, i have no idea how to edit a post, i can delete a post, i can view a post, i can create a post, but don't know how to edit a post, how does on implement this in flask python using SQLAlchemy, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as:

```
# in your edit view
...
post = Post.query.get(id)
title = request.form['title']
body = request.form['body']
post.update(title=title, body=body)
...
```

Comment: jack, how would you pass the information to jinja, on the edit.html

to view it as a draft, and edit it, you know what i mean ?

Comment: Seems like that's a separate question that would be tagged with `jinja`